# Is High CPU Usage Dangerous For My Computer?

Tags: cpu-usage, temperature

When I play Publishing Clearing House Slots, eventually Norton advises me that my CPU usage is running high. I know nothing about computer temperatures; am I at risk for damaging my computer?

Comment: Does the fan speed up when this happens?  IF so, you're probably fine.

Answer (score 3):

Usage, no, but temperature, yes, definitely. Install a tool like Speedfan or CoreTemp to monitor your CPU temperature. You can find the safe ranges for your CPU by looking up the model number, but most are getting into the danger zone at about 72°C.

Comment: This. Monitoring CPU *usage* to detect potential problems is completely useless.

Comment: indeed. with appropriate cooling, there is no reason it should not be able to run at 100% for its entire expected lifetime. I'm sure at some point the extra entropy from the constant voltage (and fluctuations thereof) will put some wear on it, but like everything else in the universe, its continually dying.

Answer (score 0):

Norton is telling you this because high CPU usage could have been caused my some malware, but you said that you know which application is causing this so you should be fine.

Just in case do a most detailed scan, after all it is possible that your game came with a virus.